# How to inline multiple SVGs with React using Webpack?

Tags: svg, reactjs, webpack

Let's say I have a dozen or more SVGs that I want to inline in my React app. Right now, I'm using [svg-react-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-react-loader) to import them like this.

```
import Svg1 from "!babel!svg-react!../../images/sdg1.svg";
import Svg2 from "!babel!svg-react!../../images/sdg2.svg";
import Svg3 from "!babel!svg-react!../../images/sdg3.svg";
import Svg4 from "!babel!svg-react!../../images/sdg4.svg";
```

...and so on. I need to set event handlers on each of them and hover events. Moreover, when one of them is selected I want to change its opacity.

After several hours and as many failed experiments, the only thing I've tried that works is to render them all inside a parent component like this.

```
const Icon = React.createClass({

    //Callback that updates the state of a parent component
    clickHandler() {
        this.props.handler(this.props.svg) 
    }

    render() {

        const icons = [
            <Svg1 className="svg1" opacity={this.props.svg === this.props.currentSvg ? 1 : 0.3} />
            <Svg2 className="svg2" opacity={this.props.svg === this.props.currentSvg ? 1 : 0.3} />
            <Svg3 className="svg3" opacity={this.props.svg === this.props.currentSvg ? 1 : 0.3} />
            <Svg4 className="svg4" opacity={this.props.svg === this.props.currentSvg ? 1 : 0.3} />
        ];

        return (
            <div className="icon" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
                {icons[this.props.svg]}
            </div>
        );
    }    
});
```

Again, this works but I'm sure this isn't the way React intended. Is there a way to iterate over SVG components created this way to assign them properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to just put them in an array and use [React.createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement):

```
const icons = [Svg1, Svg2, Svg3, Svg4];

return (
    <div className="icon" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
        {icons.map((svg, i) => React.createElement(svg, {
            className: "svg"+i,
            opacity: (this.props.svg === this.props.currentSvg ? 1 : 0.3)
         })}
    </div>
);
```

Another option, since you are using Webpack is to make use of their [dynamic require](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) functionality.

Basically you can give webpack a wildcard of files to bundle with your app and then at runtime dynamically and synchronously require them:

```
// right below your import statements
const reqSvgs = require.context("../../images", false, /\.svg$/);

// now anywhere in your code you can:
const arrayOfSVGFilenames = reqSvgs.keys();
const specificSVG = reqSvgs("../../images/svg1.svg");
const allSVGsInAnArray = reqSvgs.keys().map(reqSvgs);
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks so much. Awesome answer.

Comment: I've just tried the top part so far, with React.createElement (which I totally should have thought of). Will try the webpack solution here in a sec.