# How to import all icons at once using svg-sprite-loader?

Tags: svg, webpack, sprite

I'm trying to use https://github.com/kisenka/svg-sprite-loader this package for using svg icons in my app.

Eventually it worked, but I have to import every icon:
`import up from '@/assets/svg/up.svg'`

How can I do it once, auto-importing all icons from my svg folder?

Comment: linked - [How to inline multiple SVGs with React using Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38353987/104380)

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a module like `sprites.js` with the following (adjust your path to svgs):

```
require.context('path/to/your/svg/folder', true, /\.svg$/);
```

And include it in your entry point.

More information about `require.context` in the [official Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext)

Comment: [`require.context`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066904/104380) is webpack-specific. worth mentioning.