# What is `require.context`?

Tags: webpack

[Webpack Docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/)

> You can create your own context with the require.context() function.

Great. What is a "context"? What does this actually do?

> It allows you to pass in a directory to search, a flag indicating
>   whether subdirectories should be searched too, and a regular
>   expression to match files against.

Allows me to "search"? Search for files I'm assuming, and then what? What does this function ultimately do? What is it used for?

Comment: https://robkendal.co.uk/blog/use-webpack-and-require-context-to-load-html-files

Answer (score 146, accepted):

One of the main features of webpack's compiler is to recursively parse all the modules, starting from the entries, to build a graph of all the module dependencies by analyzing `require()`, `require.context()`, `import` and `import()` expressions.

The usual interpretation of "context" in webpack, and similarly in Node.js, is some  directory that is used as a base for resolving paths to modules. For example, the current working directory is used as the [default context](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context) for webpack to resolve the actual path to the `index.js` entry module; the context for the request `require.resolve('../../../foo.js')` is `__dirname`.

[`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext) is a special feature supported by webpack's compiler that allows you to get all matching modules starting from some base directory. The intention is to tell webpack at compile time to transform that expression into a dynamic list of all the possible matching module requests that it can resolve, in turn adding them as build dependencies and allowing you to require them at runtime.

In short, you would use `require.context` in the exact same situation when in Node.js at runtime you would use globs to dynamically build a list of module paths to require. The return value is a callable object that behaves like require, whose keys contain the necessary module request data that can be passed to it as an argument to require the module.

There are several ways you can use it, but I think the two most common use cases are to either automagically require some well-known kind of modules (e.g. you just add `some.test.js` test module and in some module you use `require.context` to dynamically discover all the tests, thus not having to document and remember to do it manually every time you add a new test module) or to load static assets in the repository to emit files to the build output (new webpack users coming from other build tools are usually surprised that their images, fonts, audio files and other assets do not appear in the output unless they are required from some module).

Comment: I have a doubt about what is returned from `require.context`
- in my currently job I faced the follow code

```
const srcContext = require.context('../src', true, /.test.jsx?$/);
srcContext.keys().forEach(srcContext);

```

**What exactly this code is doing?**

Comment: @ArmandoJúnior : as stated, suppose the returned 'srcContext' is function that does a dynamic 'require(someModule)' ; and that each 'key' is a 'module-specifier'. So the forEach will invoke  dynamic-require(module-key0); dynamic-require(module-key1);  ...  Ultimately to tell webpack that each module identified by 'require-context' is to be considered as *required*.