# Loading images results in 404 (Not Found) - webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, phaser-framework

This is the text of the error

[image]

I'm trying to load a few images in my game in Phaser 3.23.0
The images are loaded in the function preload() in the file below

main.js

```
import Phaser from 'phaser';

function preload() {
  this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
  this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
  this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
  this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
  this.load.spritesheet('dude',
    'assets/dude.png',
    { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
}

function create() {
  this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
}

function update() {
}

const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  scene: {
    preload,
    create,
    update,
  },
};

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

console.log(game);
```

I type

```
npm run webpack-dev-server --mode development
```

And starts webpack-dev-server in localhost:8080

Then I get these errors:

These are the errors in the console. Chrome browser.

[image]

These are the errors in the network. Chrome browser

[image]

These are the errors in the console. Firefox browser.

[image]

Firefox is not having any network activity. Not even one request.

index.html

```
    <!doctype html> 
    <html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Making your first Phaser 3 Game - Part 1</title>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


const config = {
  entry: './src/scripts/main.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader?name=/src/assets/[name].[ext]',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'assets/',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      'dist',
    ),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Output Management',
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode === 'development') {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
    config.output.filename = 'main.bundle.js';
  }

  if (argv.mode === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin());
    config.output.filename = 'main.[hash].bundle.js';
  }

  return config;
};
```

[This](https://github.com/IvanDerlich/space-shooter-game/tree/7fe38f39459dbab4fc23fdd69b918d8086b73d7e) is the repo at the time this question was made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have a 404.**

change you `main.js` to:

```
function preload() {
  this.load.image('sky', require("../assets/sky.png").default);
  this.load.image('ground', require("../assets/platform.png").default);
  this.load.image('star', require("../assets/star.png").default);
  this.load.image('bomb', require("../assets/bomb.png").default);
  this.load.spritesheet('dude',
  require("../assets/dude.png").default,
    { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
}
```

Now execute:

```
yarn start / npm start
```

Comment: It's working!
https://imgur.com/a/wTrEOiS
Thanks mate. You are a legend as your name states.

Comment: I commented the require.context('../assets') line and everything stills works fine. What does this function do? I've been reading https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/ and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059179/what-is-require-context and still don't understand what it does and why is neccesary.

Comment: Removed it, as it is not necessary here.

[This](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/context) explains it better. It can be used with dynamic `require`s, where you don't know upfront which resource will be required exactly. It will copy all the files specified in `require.context` to your dist folder and you will have them available at runtime.