# how to import many vue component to my vue page?

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

i dont want to write a lot of import from.

```
import button1 from './components/button1'
import button2 from './componnets/button2'
import table1 from './componnets/table2'
...
```

Is there any good way to do it quickly?
How many way to do this thing？

Answer (score 1):

following this pattern you can dynamically import components as well:

```
computed: {
  comp () {
      return () => import(`@/components/${this.componentName}.vue`)
  }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
<template>
    <component :is="comp"></component>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could import and register the Vue Components globally in your index file:

```
import button1 from './components/button1'

Vue.component('button1', button1);
```

See the official documentation for more information: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration

Comment: i dont want to global the component ,just wanna import them into one view page.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `require.context`, look at the example in [the official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components), this should be enough to solve your problem. For more information about `require.context`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059179/what-is-require-context).