# Dynamically loading CSS in Webpack 5 without CSS modules?

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am working on a legacy project (based on jQuery). Some CSS is added with Javascript by simply appending the style-tag to the header:

```
$("head").append("<link href='" + path + "' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' />")
```

I cannot rewrite the code using CSS modules so I am wondering if there is a way to bundle this CSS that gets injected via Javascript using Webpack 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to make it work using require.context.

The following line makes all js files inside a certain folder available as build dependencies:

```
var req_js = require.context("./components", true, /.js$/);
```

And this actually uses them (the jQuery code is just there because this legacy project is using jQuery, the important part is `req_js(key)`):

```
$.each(window.app.config.components, function(componentName) {

    req_js.keys().forEach(function(key){
        if (key.split('/')[1] === componentName) {
            req_js(key);  //this actually calls/uses these dependencies
        }
    });
)};
```

More interesting background info regarding require.context here: [What is `require.context`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059179/what-is-require-context)