# Vue.js - How to loop through a folder

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue SPA app. Now I want to extend this app with app modules so I thought to make a folder `src/modules` that contain the modules folders. I want to put at the root of each folder some configuration js files (store.js, route.js, and so on).
The question is: in the main files (`src/store/index.js`, `src/router/index.js`, etc.), how can I loop for every folder in `src/modules` and check if some configuration file exists to add its content at the main config? Of course this operation should be executed at build time, modules install is not intended to be dynamically.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Hmm, maybe using a build tool like Webpack or a shell script of some kind?

Comment: @user115014 I don't want to use a shell script, I prefer to use javascript inside main files. Could you answer the question with the way to achive the solution with webpack? Thank you.

Comment: Check how to access the filesystem from a stand point of a Node.js app (using `fs` mainly or `readFileSync` etc). Frontend cannot really scan local folders, just use static paths hardcoded as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [require.context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066904/5962802)

```js
const configurations = require.context('./modules', true, /config\.js$/i);
configurations.keys().forEach(filename =>
{
  console.log(filename);
  // file contents will be inside configurations[filename]
});
```